# How to set video recording time limit and compress it to 2MB in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am new to android, I am trying to develope an application which will record video for 10 seconds. This is my code.

```
 public void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FRONT)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        mediaFile = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video.mp4");

        videoUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 10);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I set in all possible ways, but I am not able to achieve my target. After attaining this, I need to compress this video to 2MB, I haven't start working on it because I stuck in capturing the video. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using MediaRecorder (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) ?